# $m+s<n$, then there exists nonzero $x \in \ker A_{m\times n} \cap \ker B_{s\times n}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_{m\times n}$,$B_{s\times n}$ be real matrices.

Prove that if $m+s<n$, then there exists nonzero $x \in \ker A \cap \ker B$.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Where does this problem come from? Also, you should give a brief outline of what you've tried, so that we can help address what you do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Rank-nullity theorem
$$
\dim\operatorname{Im}A = n - \dim \ker A\\
\dim\operatorname{Im}B = n - \dim \ker B
$$
and
\begin{align}
\dim (\ker A \cap \ker B) &= \dim \ker A + \dim \ker B -\dim(\ker A+\ker B)\\
&\geq\dim \ker A + \dim \ker B -n\\
&= 2n-\dim\operatorname{Im}A - \dim\operatorname{Im}B-n\\
&=n-\dim\operatorname{Im}A - \dim\operatorname{Im}B\\
&\geq n-m-s>0
\end{align}

Comment: How do you know, that $\dim Im A > m$ and $\dim Im B > s$?

Comment: @Josef: it is the reverse: $\dim\operatorname{Im}A\leq m$, because it is the number of independent columns, that are at most $m$. So, changing sign, $-\dim\operatorname{Im}A\geq -m$. The same holds for $B$.